# Is there an 'angel dance' outside of the Shirobako anime?

Tags: culture, shirobako

In Shirobako episode 16, Ema is caught doing a little dance exercise on the roof.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvlVueWyu18

[image]

CrunchyRoll's subtitles call this the 'Angel Dance' exercise. There's no results for that in english, but I was thinking maybe it's an exercise only really known about in Japan. For the most part, Shirobako has solid references to existing things.

Is this dance a real exercise or was it just created for the show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to what I read in [a forum](http://www.fandompost.com/oldforums/showthread.php?36321-Shirobako-Discussion-Thread&p=290346&viewfull=1#post290346):

> Ema's Angel Exercise is modelled on the real-life Angel Exercise in the 70s.
>   Bodybuilder Tsushima Seiji, under the name of Mukimuki Man (Muscular Man), comically did the Angel Exercise in the TV commercial for a sweet made by [Morinaga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morinaga_%26_Company) and also in other TV programmes in the late 70s. (Morinaga's mascot is an angel, and the founder of Morinaga & Company Morinaga Taichirō was a Christian and learnt how to make Western-style confectionery in the USA.)

Here's the video of the original Angel Exercise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpF9V3nQoK4

Comment: Please make sure to cite your sources in the future.